# Installed CU but server doesn't think so

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update

I installed KB2880552 onto all the servers in my SharePoint farm.  After the update ran, I went to our CA server and started the PSConfig executable.  The application reports that one of my servers doesn't have the upgrade.

I can go to the server and see that it was installed and when I try to run the upgrade again, it says No products are affected by this upgrade.  I can see in Add Remove programs that the update is applied (15.0.4571.1502).

Is there a way to force a reinstall of the update or force SP to relook at the server and see that it was updated?  I know it isn't supported but might there be a way to upgrade a database table somewhere with the values of a server that did upgrade fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much common issues now days.

Couple of things to try to force SharePoint that all servers having SP.

- run this command on the server where CU missing [`Get-SPProduct -Local`](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/)
- if still facing the issue, try to reboot the server